# Get the maximum value in a row

Tags: mysql

For the following table in MySQL (Prices in the table means the prices provide by different suppliers)

```
Products   | Price1 | Price2 | Price3
Apple      | 2      | 3      | 4
Pear       | 2      | 1      | 1.5
Strawberry | 10     | 12     | 11
```

How can I get the results that the maximun price for Apple is Price3, maximun price for Pear is Price1, maximun price for Strawberry is Price2, for example, I want the results to be retrieved from the table above:

```
Products     | MaximunPrice
Apple        | Price3
Pear         | Price1
Strawberry   | Price2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `GREATEST`:

```
SELECT Products,
       CASE GREATEST(Price1, Price2, Price3) 
         WHEN Price1 THEN 'Price1'
         WHEN Price2 THEN 'Price2'
         WHEN Price3 THEN 'Price3'
       END AS MaxPrice
FROM TableName
```

Result:

```
Products    MaxPrice
---------------------
Apple       Price3
Pear        Price1
Strawberry  Price2
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/763a7/2)

**Explanation:**

`GREATEST()` function returns the greatest of the given arguments.

Read more [**here**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest).

**EDIT:**

To find the greatest of `non-null` values, you can use `IFNULL` or `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT Products,
       CASE GREATEST(IFNULL(Price1,0), IFNULL(Price2,0), IFNULL(Price3,0)) 
         WHEN Price1 THEN 'Price1'
         WHEN Price2 THEN 'Price2'
         WHEN Price3 THEN 'Price3'
       END AS MaxPrice
FROM TableName
```

Result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1656a/2)

Comment: Raging Bill is being disengenuous in their response. The correct answer is to normalise your schema.

Comment: Thanks. And I have a question to follow up. If the case is that when some prices are missing, what should the query be? For example. <br/>`Products    | Price1 | Price2 | Price3`<br/>
`Apple         | 2         | 3         | 4`<br/>
`Pear           | 2         | 1         | null`<br/>
`Strawberry | null     | 12       | null`

Comment: @Strawberry: I totally agree with you. OP should normalise the data if he has the permission to do so.